# How easy to cut a turn light?

Tags: cutting, metal, woodworking

How easy would it be to cut an item like the one shown below on a laser cutter?
I might want to cut out such an item for Christmas.
As you can see I’m just decorating it with glitter at this point:

[image: turn light] [image: close-up]

Comment: Are you asking about the car/tree combination that is mounted on the flat disk, or are you asking about the illuminated rotation stand underneath the flat disk?  The former would be easy while the latter would involve gears, motors and leds, making it significantly more difficult.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cutting out the truck and trees would be pretty straight forward.  Just find equivalent vector art in whatever format your laser likes.  Online trace and format transformation websites are available to help with that step.

To make the truck and trees stand up, you will need to add a square tab to the bottom of each tire and to the base of the tree's trunk.  This tab will fit into slots which you cut in the disk portion of your project.  Inkscape is a free vector editing software which is good at making these kinds of modifications.

Just make sure to measure the thickness of the wood you are cutting all this from, and use that as the width of the slots you are cutting in disk.  That way, the tabs which you have added to your upright pieces will fit snugly into those slots.